# Problems with hfsplus on Raspberry Pi

Tags: fsck

## Description

I was following [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/276468/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-networked-time-machine-drive-for-your-mac/) to use a hard drive connected to the Raspberry Pi as a TimeMachine backup. Everything was working find until I removed for a short time the power supply of the RPi. Since that the hfsplus formatted partition on the hard drive containing the TimeMachine backup is mounted in read-only mode because of errors in the partition. Thus, I was trying to restore the corrupt partition via `fsck.hfsplus` but it was not able the remove the errors. In the end I had to format the whole partition and create the backup newly.

## Problem

Has anybody experienced similar problems with `hfsplus` formatted hard drives and the RPi?
Is there an opportunity to prevent this problem in the future?

Comment: Last time I looked HFS support on Linux lacks journalling - so is lacking the basic recovery mechanism present in ext4, and natively present in HFS (on macOS) and NTFS (on Windows). I only use non native filesystems in readonly mode.